# iOS7 NSMergeConflict on Single Thread Save

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data, ios7

Am having problems with a simple data save on a single threaded app after two rows have been re-ordered.

I've managed to simplify the coding to reproduce the error and would appreciate a second opinion with someone else trying this out.

This is a sanity check as I'm suspicious of a core-data issue introduced with iOS 7 as this worked ok in iOS 6.

Firstly, start a new core data project and create this model...

[image: simple core data model]

Attribute 'current' is an optional boolean. The one-to-many relationship is an ordered relationship, creating an NSOrderedDataset.

Now add a couple of buttons to the app; the first to create the data (a project and two associated 'drawings') and the second to swap the two drawings, then set a property within the first drawing.

Here's the code...

```
-(IBAction)onTestButton:(id)sender
{
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    self.project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    Drawing *drawing1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Drawing" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    Drawing *drawing2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Drawing" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSMutableOrderedSet* tempSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.project.drawings];
    [tempSet addObject:drawing1];
    [tempSet addObject:drawing2];
    self.project.drawings = tempSet;

    [self save];
}

-(IBAction)onTestButton2:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableOrderedSet *exchange = [self.project mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"drawings"];
    [exchange exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:1];
    self.project.drawings = exchange;

    [self save];

    Drawing *drawing = [self.project.drawings objectAtIndex:0];

    BOOL current = [drawing.current boolValue];
    drawing.current = [NSNumber numberWithBool:!current];

    [self save];
}

-(void)save
{
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if( ![managedObjectContext save:&error] )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ Save: Unresolved Error on Save %@", error, [error userInfo] );
        abort();
    }
}
```

Now, test by pressing the first test button. This sets up the data.

Then press the second test button....all OK!!!

Now press the second test button **again** and BANG.  You 'should get a NSMergeConflict error similar to this....

> Save: Unresolved Error on Save {
>       conflictList =     (
>           "NSMergeConflict (0x8a7d0b0) for NSManagedObject (0x8bedfa0) with objectID '0x8bd9340
>   ' with
>   oldVersion = 1 and newVersion = 2 and old object snapshot = {\n
>   current = \"\";\n    project = \"0x8bc3f50
>   \";\n}
>   and new cached row = {\n    current = \"\";\n    project =
>   \"0x8aa88c0
>   \";\n}"
>       );

I notice from the error that my Project object has changed. However, this is a single thread app using the main app context.

I've spent far too long on this and would appreciate someone else passing comment as to where the issue is. Is this a core-data bug, or am I being a right 'fool'?

Many thanks

/Fitto

Comment: Which of the `save` calls in `onTestButton2` causes the error?

Comment: The second. It's always after trying to change data after the saved 'exchange'

Comment: I can reproduce this, but I really don't know wtf is causing it.

Comment: Thanks. At least I know I'm not being totally stupid. I'm wondering if this is a core-data issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar issues an found a workaround here:

http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Oct/msg00657.html

In short - add this to your MOC setup:

```
  [_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:[[NSMergePolicy alloc] initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType]];
```

This affects OS X 10.9 Mavericks as well when using NSSQLStoreType. I could not repeat the Merge error using NSXMLStoreType.

For Swift 2.x

```
managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(mergeType: .MergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that fixes it. Phew!   Not sure as to why it is happening. Can only assume core-data is performing 'invisible' somersaults behind the scenes.

Comment: Don't really understand why, but this seemed to fix my crashing problem with AFIncrementalStore. Thanks a million! Have been debugging it for days.